# What is the meson equivalent of cmake's `FetchContent`?

Tags: cmake, meson-build, fetchcontent

How would I fetch a dependency from GitHub in meson? I am trying to convert the following cmake snippet into meson

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  some_dep
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/some/repo
  GIT_TAG        sometag
  SOURCE_SUBDIR  src
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(some_dep)
```

Note that this dependency may not be using meson as its build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meson equivalent is [subprojects](https://mesonbuild.com/Subprojects.html) and the [wrap dependency system](https://mesonbuild.com/Wrap-dependency-system-manual.html). Here a simple example:

- `subprojects/fmt.wrap`:

  ```ini
  [wrap-file]
  directory = fmt-7.1.3
  source_url = https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/archive/7.1.3.tar.gz
  source_filename = fmt-7.1.3.tar.gz
  source_hash = 5cae7072042b3043e12d53d50ef404bbb76949dad1de368d7f993a15c8c05ecc
  patch_url = https://wrapdb.mesonbuild.com/v1/projects/fmt/7.1.3/1/get_zip
  patch_filename = fmt-7.1.3-1-wrap.zip
  patch_hash = 6eb951a51806fd6ffd596064825c39b844c1fe1799840ef507b61a53dba08213

  [provide]
  fmt = fmt_dep
  ```

  > It is a meson convention that the directory *must* be named `subprojects` and be a top-level directory.
- `meson.build`:

  ```py
  project('demo', 'cpp')

  fmt_dep = dependency('fmt-7', required: false)
  if not fmt_dep.found()
    fmt_proj = subproject('fmt')
    fmt_dep = fmt_proj.get_variable('fmt_dep')
  endif

  executable('demo', 'main.cpp', dependencies: fmt_dep, install: true)
  ```
- `main.cpp`:

  ```cpp
  #include <fmt/core.h>
  int main() {
      fmt::print("Hello, world!\n");
  }
  ```

This will search `libfmt` on your system and fallback to downloading it as specified in the wrap file. The `subproject()` function requires a `meson.build` file in the root directory, similar to how `FetchContent` expects a `CMakeLists.txt`. If the respective project does not have meson build files, you can provide patches through the `patch_*` or `diff_files` properties in the wrap file. This is e.g. the case for [libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) does not have meson build files. You can also use `[wrap-git]` instead of `[wrap-file]` to specify a git repository instead of a release tarball. Please refer to the [documentation](https://mesonbuild.com/Wrap-dependency-system-manual.html#how-it-works).

**Tip**: The meson developers maintain the [Wrap DB](https://mesonbuild.com/Wrapdb-projects.html), where you can find wrap files for some common libraries/projects.